# Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}' Angular RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable and get some values from an API using RxJs but I have an error

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'
```

I'm using RxJs 6 and Angular 8.
The error is here

```
this.beginnersCourses$ = http$
        .pipe( 
            map(courses => courses.
                filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER'))
        );
```

Of course I defined the observable first

```
beginnersCourses$: Observable<Course[]>;
```

and the import is

```
import {map, filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

That's the http$

```
const http$ = createHttpObservable('api/courses');

        const courses$ = http$
          .pipe(
            map(res => Object.values(res["payload"]))      
        )
```

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: I think you have to subscribe to `begginersCourses$` first then use map/filter in a `pipe`

Comment: what does `http$` contains here

Comment: The filter works for array not object. Please check the data type of course. It seems an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`courses.filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')` is absolutly not related to the `filter` function of Rxjs. This is the prototype method of an array.

Your problem is that your observable does not return an array of `Course[]` (as you defined), but an objet. An object does not have a `filter` method prototype.

You have to change the return type of your observable to what it really is.

Comment: You were right. I've just changed my http$ const in const http$ : Observable<Course[]> =  createHttpObservable('api/courses'); and now it's working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to write is:

```
this.beginnersCourses$ = http$
    .pipe( 
        filter(course => course.category === 'BEGINNER'),
    );
```

Comment: I tried, but in this way i have the same error but on the "category" property

Comment: @End.Game What's `http$`?